# Outlook.com Removes Placeholder Links in Email

Tags: html, handlebars.js, html-email

I have defined an HTML email template that has an anchor tag which its `href` attribute is assigned to a handlebars.js

Something like this:

```
<td class="body-text" align="left" class="padding">For the latest information on this order, please <a href="{{orderLink}}">click here</a>.<br></td>
```

I'm using Litmus to preview all the Email clients available but notice that in Outlook 365 it would show the content inside the email between brackets.

After some research, I came with this issue in their [official repository](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/10). So, Outlook expects to add the full URL but I'm sending a handlebars.js variable instead. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to compile the handlebars template with the variables before looking at it on outlook? I would definitely try that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to this issue:
http://freshinbox.com/blog/outlook-com-removes-placeholder-links-in-email/

Outlook.com and Office 365 don't like dummy or empty links and subsequently you'll see broken templates in Litmus tests.
For testing purposes, it'll be best to follow the steps in the article I linked and test again.

Comment: So, I had to test with real URL and worked! I used this one: http://www.example.com/